# How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, bluebird

I want to work with promises but I have a callback API in a format like:

#### 1. DOM load or other one time event:

```
window.onload; // set to callback
...
window.onload = function() {

};
```

#### 2. Plain callback:

```
function request(onChangeHandler) {
    ...
}
request(function() {
    // change happened
    ...
});
```

#### 3. Node style callback ("nodeback"):

```
function getStuff(dat, callback) {
    ...
}
getStuff("dataParam", function(err, data) {
    ...
})
```

#### 4. A whole library with node style callbacks:

```
API;
API.one(function(err, data) {
    API.two(function(err, data2) {
        API.three(function(err, data3) {
            ...
        });
    });
});
```

#### How do I work with the API in promises, how do I "promisify" it?

Comment: I posted my own answer but answers expanding on how to do this for a specific library or in more circumstances and edits too are very much welcome.

Comment: @Bergi That's an interesting idea, I tried to make a general answer that uses the two common approaches (Promise constructor and deferred object). I tried to give the two alternatives in answers. I agree that RTFMing solves this issue but we run into this issue often both here and in the bug tracker so I figured a 'canonical question' is in place - I think RTFMing solves about 50% of the issues in the JS tag :D If you have an interesting insight to contribute in an answer or edit it'd be very appreciated.

Comment: Does creating a `new Promise` add any significant overhead?  I'm wanting to wrap all my synchronous Noje.js functions in a Promise so as to remove all synchronous code from my Node app, but is this best practice? In other words, a function that accepts a static argument(e.g. a string) and returns a calculated result, should I wrap that in a promise?  ...I read somewhere that you should not have any synchronous code in Nodejs.

Comment: @RonRoyston no, it is not a good idea to wrap synchronous calls with promises - only asynchronous calls that may perform I/O

Answer (score 869, accepted):

Promises have state, they start as pending and can settle to:

- **fulfilled** meaning that the computation completed successfully.
- **rejected** meaning that the computation failed.

Promise returning functions [*should never throw*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21887856/1048572), they should return rejections instead. Throwing from a promise returning function will force you to use both a `} catch {` *and* a `.catch`. People using promisified APIs do not expect promises to throw. If you're not sure how async APIs work in JS - please [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/16825593#16825593) first.

#### 1. DOM load or other one time event:

So, creating promises generally means specifying when they settle - that means when they move to the fulfilled or rejected phase to indicate the data is available (and can be accessed with `.then`).

With modern promise implementations that support the `Promise` constructor like native ES6 promises:

```
function load() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        window.onload = resolve;
    });
}
```

You would then use the resulting promise like so:

```
load().then(function() {
    // Do things after onload
});
```

With libraries that support deferred (Let's use $q for this example here, but we'll also use jQuery later):

```
function load() {
    var d = $q.defer();
    window.onload = function() { d.resolve(); };
    return d.promise;
}
```

Or with a jQuery like API, hooking on an event happening once:

```
function done() {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    $("#myObject").once("click",function() {
        d.resolve();
    });
    return d.promise();
}
```

#### 2. Plain callback:

These APIs are rather common since well… callbacks are common in JS. Let's look at the common case of having `onSuccess` and `onFail`:

```
function getUserData(userId, onLoad, onFail) { …
```

With modern promise implementations that support the `Promise` constructor like native ES6 promises:

```
function getUserDataAsync(userId) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        getUserData(userId, resolve, reject);
    });
}
```

With libraries that support deferred (Let's use jQuery for this example here, but we've also used $q above):

```
function getUserDataAsync(userId) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    getUserData(userId, function(res){ d.resolve(res); }, function(err){ d.reject(err); });
    return d.promise();
}
```

jQuery also offers a `$.Deferred(fn)` form, which has the advantage of allowing us to write an expression that emulates very closely the `new Promise(fn)` form, as follows:

```
function getUserDataAsync(userId) {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
        getUserData(userId, dfrd.resolve, dfrd.reject);
    }).promise();
}
```

Note: Here we exploit the fact that a jQuery deferred's `resolve` and `reject` methods are "detachable"; ie. they are bound to the *instance* of a jQuery.Deferred(). Not all libs offer this feature.

#### 3. Node style callback ("nodeback"):

Node style callbacks (nodebacks) have a particular format where the callbacks is always the last argument and its first parameter is an error. Let's first promisify one manually:

```
getStuff("dataParam", function(err, data) { …
```

To:

```
function getStuffAsync(param) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        getStuff(param, function(err, data) {
            if (err !== null) reject(err);
            else resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

With deferreds you can do the following (let's use Q for this example, although Q now supports the new syntax [which you should prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28687566/1048572)):

```
function getStuffAsync(param) {
    var d = Q.defer();
    getStuff(param, function(err, data) {
        if (err !== null) d.reject(err);
        else d.resolve(data);
    });
    return d.promise;   
}
```

In general, you should not promisify things manually too much, most promise libraries that were designed with Node in mind as well as native promises in Node 8+ have a built in method for promisifying nodebacks. For example

```
var getStuffAsync = Promise.promisify(getStuff); // Bluebird
var getStuffAsync = Q.denodeify(getStuff); // Q
var getStuffAsync = util.promisify(getStuff); // Native promises, node only
```

#### 4. A whole library with node style callbacks:

There is no golden rule here, you promisify them one by one. However, some promise implementations allow you to do this in bulk, for example in Bluebird, converting a nodeback API to a promise API is as simple as:

```
Promise.promisifyAll(API);
```

Or with *native promises* in **Node**:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const promiseAPI = Object.entries(API).map(([key, v]) => ({key, fn: promisify(v)}))
                         .reduce((o, p) => Object.assign(o, {[p.key]: p.fn}), {});
```

Notes:

- Of course, when you are in a `.then` handler you do not need to promisify things. Returning a promise from a `.then` handler will resolve or reject with that promise's value. Throwing from a `.then` handler is also good practice and will reject the promise - this is the famous promise throw safety.
- In an actual `onload` case, you should use `addEventListener` rather than `onX`.

Comment: Benjamin, I accepted your invitation to edit and added a further jQuery example to case 2. It will need peer reviewing before it appears. Hope you like it.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 it got rejected since I didn't see and accept it in time. For what it's worth I don't think the addition is too relevant although useful.

Comment: Benjamin, whether or not `resolve()` and `reject()` are written to be reusable, I venture that my suggested edit is relevant because it offers a jQuery example of the form `$.Deferred(fn)`, which is otherwise lacking. If only one jQuery example is included, then I suggest that it should be of this form rather than `var d = $.Deferred();` etc. as people should be encouraged to use the oft neglected `$.Deferred(fn)` form, plus, in an answer like this, it puts jQuery more on a par with libs that use the [Revealing Constructor Pattern](http://domenic.me).

Comment: Heh, to be 100% fair I didn't know jQuery let you do `$.Deferred(fn)`, if you edit that in instead of the existing example in the next 15 minutes I'm sure I can try to approve it on time :)

Comment: Benjamin, sorry I missed your 15 minute deadline but will try to catch you online soon. I'm sort of pleased my earlier edit wasn't accepted as I've had a chance to amend it to something better. It will need to be an addition, not a replacement.

Comment: What are you referring to when you write "modern promise implementation"? What are you including to be able to use the `Promise` constructor?

Comment: @fraxture pretty much every implementation written after the Promises/A+ spec and the consteuctor spec was born or was altered because of it to match it - these are most promises we know : Q, Bluebird, When, RSVP, $q (since 1.3), native promises, jQuery starting with the next version and so on.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: got ya. But what do I need to include to use the Promise constructor? Installing Q with npm and then requring it did not work...

Comment: With Q it's called Q.Promise - the API docs of Q are good and cover this.

Comment: The answer was that I needed to `npm install promise --save` and then `var Promise = require('promise')` in order to be able to `new Promise`.

Comment: Don't use that library - use Bluebied instead.

Comment: What happens if my onX event can happen multiple times. Can this also promisified?

Comment: No, if a callback happens multiple times it should _not_ be promisified, promises are for one time things. For things that happen multiple times the easiest thing would be to use an event emitter - more advanced patterns like async iterators (iterators of promises) or observables (push object streams) exist. Promises are only for one time things.

Comment: I have a question about number 3 with nested callbacks. How come I can't simply call `reject/resolve`? It seems that at least in my case, I have to return them.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I want to ask regarding the 3rd heading promisify method, though it converts a callback to promise but is it possible to handle error exactly where I am making it a promise?

Comment: It seems that this answer included everything except the actual usage of a promisified function. I added an example of the load functions use after it was promisified.

Comment: This is a great answer. You may want to update it by mentioning also `util.promisify`, that Node.js is going to add to its core starting from RC 8.0.0.
Its working it's not much different from Bluebird `Promise.promisify`, but has the advantage of not requiring additional dependencies, in case you just want native Promise.
I've written a blog post about [util.promisify](https://brunoscopelliti.com/new-util-promisify-in-nodejs/) for anyone who want read more on the topic.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum A few days ago, I sent an edit propose to you last code: `const promiseAPI = Object.keys(API).map(key => {return {key, fn:util.promisify(API[key])} }).reduce((o, p) => Object.assign(o, {[p.key] : p.fn}), {});` Why did you rejected?

Comment: @robe007 probably just butter fingers - sorry! I edited it in now.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Please, see it again, your code still wrong. Look on my [edit proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20037560) few days ago.

Comment: @robe007 I did - I think the way I fixed it works - there are two ways to return objects from arrow functions: either adding a return to the block body `x => { return {}}` or to mark it as an expression `x => ({})` - both are valid and work. Maybe I'm still missing your point?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes I know my friend, but you are missing to close the _curly bracket_ in the returned object `{key, fn: util.promisify(API[key])}` from your `map`. You see it?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I have sent another [edit proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20056732) again to your last modification.

Comment: That `load` implementation looks unreliable: (1) it overrides `onload` instead of using `addEventListener`; (2) it will never resolve if the `load` event has already happened

Comment: Yes that has been discussed see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27935772/1348195 :)

Answer (score 66):

Today, I can use `Promise` in `Node.js` as a plain Javascript method.

A simple and basic example to `Promise` (with **[KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)** way):

**Plain** Javascript Async API code:

```
function divisionAPI (number, divider, successCallback, errorCallback) {

    if (divider == 0) {
        return errorCallback( new Error("Division by zero") )
    }

    successCallback( number / divider )

}
```

**`Promise`** Javascript Async API code:

```
function divisionAPI (number, divider) {

    return new Promise(function (fulfilled, rejected) {

        if (divider == 0) {
            return rejected( new Error("Division by zero") )
        }

        fulfilled( number / divider )

     })

}
```

(I recommend visiting [this beautiful source](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html))

Also `Promise` can be used with together `async\await` in `ES7` to make the program flow wait for a `fullfiled` result like the following:

```
function getName () {

    return new Promise(function (fulfilled, rejected) {

        var name = "John Doe";

        // wait 3000 milliseconds before calling fulfilled() method
        setTimeout ( 
            function() {
                fulfilled( name )
            }, 
            3000
        )

    })

}


async function foo () {

    var name = await getName(); // awaits for a fulfilled result!

    console.log(name); // the console writes "John Doe" after 3000 milliseconds

}


foo() // calling the foo() method to run the code
```

Another usage with the same code by using `.then()` method

```
function getName () {

    return new Promise(function (fulfilled, rejected) {

        var name = "John Doe";

        // wait 3000 milliseconds before calling fulfilled() method
        setTimeout ( 
            function() {
                fulfilled( name )
            }, 
            3000
        )

    })

}


// the console writes "John Doe" after 3000 milliseconds
getName().then(function(name){ console.log(name) })
```

`Promise` can also be used on any platform that is based on Node.js like `react-native`.

**Bonus**: An **hybrid** method 
(The callback method is assumed to have two parameters as error and result)

```
function divisionAPI (number, divider, callback) {

    return new Promise(function (fulfilled, rejected) {

        if (divider == 0) {
            let error = new Error("Division by zero")
            callback && callback( error )
            return rejected( error )
        }

        let result = number / divider
        callback && callback( null, result )
        fulfilled( result )

     })

}
```

The above method can respond result for old fashion callback and Promise usages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: These do not seem to show how to convert to promises.

Answer (score 41):

**Before converting a function as promise In Node.JS**

```
var request = require('request'); //http wrapped module

function requestWrapper(url, callback) {
    request.get(url, function (err, response) {
      if (err) {
        callback(err);
      }else{
        callback(null, response);             
      }      
    })
}


requestWrapper(url, function (err, response) {
    console.log(err, response)
})
```

**After Converting It**

```
var request = require('request');

function requestWrapper(url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { //returning promise
    request.get(url, function (err, response) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err); //promise reject
      }else{
        resolve(response); //promise resolve
      }
    })
  })
}


requestWrapper('http://localhost:8080/promise_request/1').then(function(response){
    console.log(response) //resolve callback(success)
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error) //reject callback(failure)
})
```

**Incase you need to handle multiple request**

```
var allRequests = [];
allRequests.push(requestWrapper('http://localhost:8080/promise_request/1')) 
allRequests.push(requestWrapper('http://localhost:8080/promise_request/2'))
allRequests.push(requestWrapper('http://localhost:8080/promise_request/5'))    

Promise.all(allRequests).then(function (results) {
  console.log(results);//result will be array which contains each promise response
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err)
});
```

Answer (score 26):

Node.js 8.0.0 includes a new `util.promisify()` API that allows standard Node.js callback style APIs to be wrapped in a function that returns a Promise. An example use of `util.promisify()` is shown below.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

readFile('/some/file')
  .then((data) => { /* ... */ })
  .catch((err) => { /* ... */ });
```

See [Improved support for Promises](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v8.0.0/#improved-support-for-promises)

Comment: There are already two answers describing this, why post a third one?

Comment: Just because that version of node is now released, and I've reported "official" feature description and link.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I upvoted this because it was the less 'cluttered' and effective one. The one at the top has so many other things that the answer gets lost.

Answer (score 26):

### A simple generic function I normally use.

```
const promisify = (fn, ...args) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn(...args, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
};
```

### How to use it

- The function `promisify` accepts a function with a callback:

```js
   const cb = (result) => `The result is ${result}`;

   const sum = (a, b, cb) => {
    const result = a + b;
    cb(result); // passing args to the callback function
   }


  // using the util
  promise = promisify(sum, 3, 1, cb);
  promise.then(x => console.log(x)) // 4
```

You are probably not looking for this answer, but this will help understand the inner workings of the available utils

Comment: I'm trying to use this, but if I call `promisify(fn, arg1, arg2).then(() => { alert("Done!"); });` the alert is never fired. Would you expect this to work?

Comment: Thanks, @Philip Stratford for the question. The `promisify` is used to convert a function with a callback into a promise. I will update my answer to explain this.

Comment: I will be happy to hear any suggestions on this solution, cc @Philip Stratford.  Thank you

Comment: const promisify = (fn, ...args) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn.apply(null, args.concat((err, result) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(result);
    }));

  });
};



const cb = (result) => result;

const sum = (a, b, cb, t) => {
  t('rr', cb(a + b))
}


promise = promisify(sum, 3, 1, cb);
promise.then(x => console.log(x)).catch((err) => console.log(err)) // 4

Answer (score 25):

I don't think the `window.onload` suggestion by @Benjamin will work all the time, as it doesn't detect whether it is called after the load. I have been bitten by that many times. Here is a version which should always work:

```
function promiseDOMready() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") return resolve();
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", resolve);
    });
}
promiseDOMready().then(initOnLoad);
```

Comment: shouldn't the "already complete" branch use `setTimeout(resolve, 0)` (or `setImmediate`, if available) to ensure that it's called asynchronously?

Comment: @Alnitak Calling `resolve` synchronously is fine. The Promise's `then` handlers are [guaranteed by the framework to be called asynchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38062501/1426891), regardless of whether `resolve` is called synchronously.

Answer (score 15):

In release candidate for Node.js 8.0.0, there's a new utility, `util.promisify` (I've written about [util.promisify](https://brunoscopelliti.com/new-util-promisify-in-nodejs/)), that encapsulates the capacity of promisifying whatever function.

It is not much different from the approaches suggested in the other answers, but has the advantage of being a core method, and not requiring additional dependencies.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
```

Then you've a `readFile` method that returns a native `Promise`.

```
readFile('./notes.txt')
  .then(txt => console.log(txt))
  .catch(...);
```

Comment: Hey, I (OP) actually suggested `util.promisify` twice (back in 2014 when this question was written, and a few months ago - which I pushed for as a core member of Node and is the current version we have in Node). Since it is not yet publicly available - I did not add it to this answer yet. We would deeply appreciate usage feedback though and getting to know what some pitfalls are in order to have better docs for the release :)

Comment: In addition, you might want to discuss the custom flag for promisifying with `util.promisify` in your blog post :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Do you mean the fact that using the `util.promisify.custom` symbol it is possible to override the result of util.promisify?

To be honest this was an intentional miss, cause I'm not yet able to find a useful use case. Perhaps you can give me some inputs?

Comment: Sure, consider APIs like `fs.exists` or APIs that do not follow the Node convention - a bluebird `Promise.promisify ` would get them wrong, but `util.promisify` gets them right.

Answer (score 8):

You can use JavaScript native promises with Node JS.

My Cloud 9 code link: https://ide.c9.io/adx2803/native-promises-in-node

```
/**
* Created by dixit-lab on 20/6/16.
*/

var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');   //Simplified HTTP request client.


var app = express();

function promisify(url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                resolve(body);
            }
            else {
                reject(error);
            }
        })
    });
}

//get all the albums of a user who have posted post 100
app.get('/listAlbums', function (req, res) {
    //get the post with post id 100
    promisify('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/100').then(function (result) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(result);
        return promisify('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + obj.userId + '/albums')
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        res.end(result);
    })
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})

//run webservice on browser : http://localhost:8081/listAlbums
```

Answer (score 8):

With plain old vanilla javaScript, here's a solution to promisify an api callback.

```
function get(url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', url);
        xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    console.log('successful ... should call callback ... ');
                    callback(null, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                } else {
                    console.log('error ... callback with error data ... ');
                    callback(xhr, null);
                }
            }
        });
        xhr.send();
    }

/**
     * @function promisify: convert api based callbacks to promises
     * @description takes in a factory function and promisifies it
     * @params {function} input function to promisify
     * @params {array} an array of inputs to the function to be promisified
     * @return {function} promisified function
     * */
    function promisify(fn) {
        return function () {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                fn.apply(null, args.concat(function (err, result) {
                    if (err) reject(err);
                    else resolve(result);
                }));
            });
        }
    }

var get_promisified = promisify(get);
var promise = get_promisified('some_url');
promise.then(function (data) {
        // corresponds to the resolve function
        console.log('successful operation: ', data);
}, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

The Q library by kriskowal includes callback-to-promise functions.
A method like this:

```
obj.prototype.dosomething(params, cb) {
  ...blah blah...
  cb(error, results);
}
```

can be converted with Q.ninvoke

```
Q.ninvoke(obj,"dosomething",params).
then(function(results) {
});
```

Comment: The canonical answer already mentions `Q.denodeify`. Do we need to emphasize library helpers?

Comment: i found this useful as a google about promisifying in Q leads here

Answer (score 5):

When you have a few functions that take a callback and you want them to return a promise instead you can use this function to do the conversion.

```
function callbackToPromise(func){

    return function(){

        // change this to use what ever promise lib you are using
        // In this case i'm using angular $q that I exposed on a util module

        var defered = util.$q.defer();

        var cb = (val) => {
            defered.resolve(val);
        }

        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        args.push(cb);    
        func.apply(this, args);

        return defered.promise;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Under node v7.6+ which has built in promises and async:

```
// promisify.js
let promisify = fn => (...args) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        fn(...args, (err, result) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve(result);
        })
    );

module.exports = promisify;
```

How to use:

```
let readdir = require('fs').readdir;
let promisify = require('./promisify');
let readdirP = promisify(readdir);

async function myAsyncFn(path) {
    let entries = await readdirP(path);
    return entries;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Node.js 8 you can **promisify** object methods *on the fly* using this npm module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/doasync

It uses **util.promisify** and **Proxies** so that your objects stay unchanged. **Memoization** is also done with the use of WeakMaps). Here are some examples:

With objects:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const doAsync = require('doasync');

doAsync(fs).readFile('package.json', 'utf8')
  .then(result => {
    console.dir(JSON.parse(result), {colors: true});
  });
```

With functions:

```
doAsync(request)('http://www.google.com')
  .then(({body}) => {
    console.log(body);
    // ...
  });
```

You can even use native `call` and `apply` to bind some context:

```
doAsync(myFunc).apply(context, params)
  .then(result => { /*...*/ });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **native Promise** in ES6, for exemple dealing with setTimeout:

```
enqueue(data) {

    const queue = this;
    // returns the Promise
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(()=> {
                queue.source.push(data);
                resolve(queue); //call native resolve when finish
            }
            , 10); // resolve() will be called in 10 ms
    });

}
```

In this exemple, the Promise has no reason to fail, so `reject()` is never called.

Answer (score 2):

The **callback style** function always like this(almost all function in node.js is this style):

```
//fs.readdir(path[, options], callback)
fs.readdir('mypath',(err,files)=>console.log(files))
```

This style has same feature:

1. the callback function is passed by last argument.
2. the callback function always accept the error object as it's first argument.

So, you could write a function for convert a function with this style like this:

```
const R =require('ramda')

/**
 * A convenient function for handle error in callback function.
 * Accept two function res(resolve) and rej(reject) ,
 * return a wrap function that accept a list arguments,
 * the first argument as error, if error is null,
 * the res function will call,else the rej function.
 * @param {function} res the function which will call when no error throw
 * @param {function} rej the function which will call when  error occur
 * @return {function} return a function that accept a list arguments,
 * the first argument as error, if error is null, the res function
 * will call,else the rej function
 **/
const checkErr = (res, rej) => (err, ...data) => R.ifElse(
    R.propEq('err', null),
    R.compose(
        res,
        R.prop('data')
    ),
    R.compose(
        rej,
        R.prop('err')
    )
)({err, data})

/**
 * wrap the callback style function to Promise style function,
 * the callback style function must restrict by convention:
 * 1. the function must put the callback function where the last of arguments,
 * such as (arg1,arg2,arg3,arg...,callback)
 * 2. the callback function must call as callback(err,arg1，arg2,arg...)
 * @param {function} fun the callback style function to transform
 * @return {function} return the new function that will return a Promise,
 * while the origin function throw a error, the Promise will be Promise.reject(error),
 * while the origin function work fine, the Promise will be Promise.resolve(args: array),
 * the args is which callback function accept
 * */
 const toPromise = (fun) => (...args) => new Promise(
    (res, rej) => R.apply(
        fun,
        R.append(
            checkErr(res, rej),
            args
        )
    )
)
```

For more concise, above example used ramda.js. Ramda.js is a excellent library for functional programming. In above code, we used it's **apply**(like javascript `function.prototype.apply`) and append(like javascript `function.prototype.push` ).
So, we could convert the a callback style function to promise style function now:

```
const {readdir} = require('fs')
const readdirP = toPromise(readdir)
readdir(Path)
    .then(
        (files) => console.log(files),
        (err) => console.log(err)
    )
```

**toPromise** and **checkErr** function is own by [berserk](https://github.com/jituanlin/berserk) library, it's a functional programming library fork by **ramda.js**(create by me).

Hope this answer is useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

`es6-promisify` converts callback-based functions to Promise-based functions.

```
const promisify = require('es6-promisify');

const promisedFn = promisify(callbackedFn, args);
```

Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promisify

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
// @flow

const toPromise = (f: (any) => void) => {
  return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      f((result) => {
        resolve(result)
      })
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e)
    }
  })
}

export default toPromise
```

Then use it

```
async loadData() {
  const friends = await toPromise(FriendsManager.loadFriends)

  console.log(friends)
}
```

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure what this adds to existing answers (maybe clarify?). Also, there is no need for the try/catch inside the promise constructor (it does this automatically for you). It's also unclear what functions this works for (that call the callback with a single argument on success? How are errors handled?)

Answer (score 1):

My promisify version of a `callback` function is the `P` function:

```js
var P = function() {
  var self = this;
  var method = arguments[0];
  var params = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (method && typeof(method) == 'function') {
      params.push(function(err, state) {
        if (!err) return resolve(state)
        else return reject(err);
      });
      method.apply(self, params);
    } else return reject(new Error('not a function'));
  });
}
var callback = function(par, callback) {
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
  return rnd > 1 ? callback(null, par) : callback(new Error("trap"));
}

callback("callback", (err, state) => err ? console.error(err) : console.log(state))
callback("callback", (err, state) => err ? console.error(err) : console.log(state))
callback("callback", (err, state) => err ? console.error(err) : console.log(state))
callback("callback", (err, state) => err ? console.error(err) : console.log(state))

P(callback, "promise").then(v => console.log(v)).catch(e => console.error(e))
P(callback, "promise").then(v => console.log(v)).catch(e => console.error(e))
P(callback, "promise").then(v => console.log(v)).catch(e => console.error(e))
P(callback, "promise").then(v => console.log(v)).catch(e => console.error(e))
```

The `P` function requires that the callback signature must be `callback(error,result)`.

Comment: What advantage does this have over native promisify or over the answers above?

Comment: What do you mean for native promisify?

Comment: [`util.promisify(fn)`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

Comment: ah yes of course :). Just and example to show the basic idea. In fact you can see how even the native one requires that the function signature must some defined like `(err, value) => ...` or you must define a custom one (see Custom promisified functions). Thank you good catcha.

Comment: @loretoparisi FYI, `var P = function (fn, ...args) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => fn.call(this, ...args, (error, result) => error ? reject(error) : resolve(result))); };` would do the same thing as yours and it's a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the implementation of how a function (callback API) can be converted to a promise.

```
function promisify(functionToExec) {
  return function() {
    var array = Object.values(arguments);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      array.push(resolve)
      try {
         functionToExec.apply(null, array);
      } catch (error) {
         reject(error)
      }
    })
  }
}

// USE SCENARIO

function apiFunction (path, callback) { // Not a promise
  // Logic
}

var promisedFunction = promisify(apiFunction);

promisedFunction('path').then(()=>{
  // Receive the result here (callback)
})

// Or use it with await like this
let result = await promisedFunction('path');
```

Answer (score 1):

Promises always have a `resolve` and a `reject`. When you write an async wrapper, just call the resolve and there you go.

You can write a wrapper function for pretty much any function taking a callback like so:

```javascript
const myAsyncWrapper = (...params) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    someFunctionWithCallback(...params, (error, response) =>
      error ? reject(error) : resolve(response)
    )
  );
```

You can take this further to write a conversion function of callbacks to promises:

```javascript
const promisify =
  (functionWithCallback) =>
  (...params) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      functionWithCallback(...params, (error, response) =>
        error ? reject(error) : resolve(response)
      )
    );
```

This concept of wrapper functions is especially useful when using older libraries or SDKs. For example, consider the Facebook Graph API's JavaScript SDK, which uses a similar callback structure for making API requests.

```javascript
FB.api(apiURL, options, function (request) {
  if (request.error || !request) return;
  // handle request
});
```

In modern applications, it is much more useful to use a promise-based API.
If you use a function only once or twice, it may be better to promisify the response individually:

```javascript
// in an async function
const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  FB.api(apiURL, (res) => (res?.error ? reject(res?.error) : resolve(res)))
);
```

If you use the function a lot, you can use the same wrapper concept to write a function like so:

```javascript
const apiWrapper = (...params) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    FB.api(...params, (res) => (res?.error ? reject(res?.error) : resolve(res)))
  );
```

Although promisifiers are great sometimes, they won't work for specific instances like this. In times like these, look on Github for a modern wrapper, or write your own like this.

Answer (score 0):

### Perhaps already answered, but this is how I do it typically:

```
// given you've defined this `Future` fn somewhere:
const Future = fn => {return new Promise((r,t) => fn(r,t))}

// define an eventFn that takes a promise `resolver`
const eventFn = resolve => {
  // do event related closure actions here. When finally done, call `resolve()`
  something.oneventfired = e => {resolve(e)}
}

// invoke eventFn in an `async` workflowFn using `Future`
// to obtain a `promise` wrapper
const workflowFn = async () => {await Future(eventFn)}
```

> Especially for things like `indexedDb` event wrappers to simplify usage.

Or you might find this variation of `Future` to be more general purpose

```
class PromiseEx extends Promise {
  resolve(v,...a) {
    this.settled = true; this.settledValue = v;
    return(this.resolve_(v,...a))
  }
  reject(v,...a) {
    this.settled = false; this.settledValue = v;
    return(this.reject_(v,...a))
  }
  static Future(fn,...args) {
    let r,t,ft = new PromiseEx((r_,t_) => {r=r_;t=t_})
    ft.resolve_ = r; ft.reject_ = t; fn(ft,...args);
    return(ft)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Necromancing a little, bit this [link](https://gist.github.com/jonathan-annett/1a8ae0cc504427317ba2912d2620aae5) may be useful....

---

### TLDR; look at the snippet example at the end of this answer

---

## write/convert functions that can be called expecting

## a `cb(error,result)` or `new Promise (...)` format

---

- `promiseToCB` converts and exports an existing function that's been previously coded to return a promise
- `cbToPromise` converts and exports an existing function that's been previously coded to call the last argument with (error,result)

  - if wrapped function supplies more than 1 result, the result will be an array of results
  - eg `cb(undefined,path,stat)` ---> `resolve([path,stat])` / `cb(undefined,[path,stat])`
- `asPromise` lets you code a new function to return a promise, but it can be called either way
- `asCallback` lets you code a new function to call `cb(err,result)`, but it can be invoked either way

### sample functions

each sample takes 2 arguments, and resolves/rejects/errors based on random number.

arg2 can be also be used to force pass or fail. (looks for "-pass" or "-fail").

### wrap existing functions

- exports the function to current "this" (or use `promiseToCB(function myFunc(){},newThis);` )

---

```js
    promiseToCB(function sampleFunc1(arg1,arg2) {
        console.log("deciding:",arg1,arg2);
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
       
           const timer = setTimeout(function(){reject([arg1,arg2,"ouch"].join("-"));},5000);
           
           setTimeout(function(){
               if (arg2.endsWith("-pass") || (!arg2.endsWith("-fail") && Math.random()<0.5)) {
    
                   console.log("complete:",arg1,arg2);
                   clearTimeout(timer);
                   resolve([arg1,arg2,"all good"].join("-"));
               }
           },2000);
        
        });
    });
    
    cbToPromise('sampleFunc2',function someOtherName(arg1,arg2,cb) {
       console.log("deciding:",arg1,arg2);
       const timer = setTimeout(function(){cb([arg1,arg2,"ouch"].join("-"));},5000);
       
       setTimeout(function(){
           if (arg2.endsWith("-pass") || (!arg2.endsWith("-fail") && Math.random()<0.5)) {
               console.log("complete:",arg1,arg2);
               clearTimeout(timer);
               cb(undefined,[arg1,arg2,"all good"].join("-"));
           }
       },2000);
        
    },local);
```

### or code new functions, which embed a wrapper.

```js
     function sampleFunc3(arg1,arg2) {return asPromise(arguments,function(resolve,reject){
       console.log("deciding:",arg1,arg2);
       const timer = setTimeout(function(){reject([arg1,arg2,"ouch"].join("-"));},5000);
       
       setTimeout(function(){
           if (arg2.endsWith("-pass") || (!arg2.endsWith("-fail") && Math.random()<0.5)) {
               console.log("complete:",arg1,arg2);
               clearTimeout(timer);
               resolve([arg1,arg2,"all good"].join("-"));
           }
       },2000);
        
    });}
    
    function sampleFunc4(arg1,arg2) {return asCallback(arguments,function(cb){
       console.log("deciding:",arg1,arg2);
       const timer = setTimeout(function(){cb([arg1,arg2,"ouch"].join("-"));},5000);
       
       setTimeout(function(){
           if (arg2.endsWith("-pass") || (!arg2.endsWith("-fail") && Math.random()<0.5)) {
               console.log("complete:",arg1,arg2);
               clearTimeout(timer);
               cb(undefined,[arg1,arg2,"all good"].join("-"));
           }
       },2000);
        
    });}
```

### test scipt for above functions

```js
    const local = {}; 
    promiseToCB(function sampleFunc1(arg1,arg2) {
        console.log("deciding:",arg1,arg2);
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
       
           const timer = setTimeout(function(){reject([arg1,arg2,"ouch"].join("-"));},5000);
           
           setTimeout(function(){
               if (arg2.endsWith("-pass") || (!arg2.endsWith("-fail") && Math.random()<0.5)) {
    
                   console.log("complete:",arg1,arg2);
                   clearTimeout(timer);
                   resolve([arg1,arg2,"all good"].join("-"));
               }
           },2000);
        
        });
    });
    
    cbToPromise('sampleFunc2',function someOtherName(arg1,arg2,cb) {
       console.log("deciding:",arg1,arg2);
       const timer = setTimeout(function(){cb([arg1,arg2,"ouch"].join("-"));},5000);
       
       setTimeout(function(){
           if (arg2.endsWith("-pass") || (!arg2.endsWith("-fail") && Math.random()<0.5)) {
               console.log("complete:",arg1,arg2);
               clearTimeout(timer);
               cb(undefined,[arg1,arg2,"all good"].join("-"));
           }
       },2000);
        
    },local);
    
    function sampleFunc3(arg1,arg2) {return asPromise(arguments,function(resolve,reject){
       console.log("deciding:",arg1,arg2);
       const timer = setTimeout(function(){reject([arg1,arg2,"ouch"].join("-"));},5000);
       
       setTimeout(function(){
           if (arg2.endsWith("-pass") || (!arg2.endsWith("-fail") && Math.random()<0.5)) {
               console.log("complete:",arg1,arg2);
               clearTimeout(timer);
               resolve([arg1,arg2,"all good"].join("-"));
           }
       },2000);
        
    });}
    
    function sampleFunc4(arg1,arg2) {return asCallback(arguments,function(cb){
       console.log("deciding:",arg1,arg2);
       const timer = setTimeout(function(){cb([arg1,arg2,"ouch"].join("-"));},5000);
       
       setTimeout(function(){
           if (arg2.endsWith("-pass") || (!arg2.endsWith("-fail") && Math.random()<0.5)) {
               console.log("complete:",arg1,arg2);
               clearTimeout(timer);
               cb(undefined,[arg1,arg2,"all good"].join("-"));
           }
       },2000);
        
    });}
    
    const log=console.log.bind(console),info=console.info.bind(console),error=console.error.bind(console);
    
    sampleFunc1("sample1","promise").then (log).catch(error);
    local.sampleFunc2("sample2","promise").then (log).catch(error);
    sampleFunc3("sample3","promise").then (log).catch(error);
    sampleFunc4("sample4","promise").then (log).catch(error);

    sampleFunc1("sample1","callback",info);
    local.sampleFunc2("sample2","callback",info);
    sampleFunc3("sample3","callback",info);
    sampleFunc4("sample4","callback",info);
    
    sampleFunc1("sample1","promise-pass").then (log).catch(error);
    local.sampleFunc2("sample2","promise-pass").then (log).catch(error);
    sampleFunc3("sample3","promise-pass").then (log).catch(error);
    sampleFunc4("sample4","promise-pass").then (log).catch(error);

    sampleFunc1("sample1","callback-pass",info);
    local.sampleFunc2("sample2","callback-pass",info);
    sampleFunc3("sample3","callback-pass",info);
    sampleFunc4("sample4","callback-pass",info);
    
    
    sampleFunc1("sample1","promise-fail").then (log).catch(error);
    local.sampleFunc2("sample2","promise-fail").then (log).catch(error);
    sampleFunc3("sample3","promise-fail").then (log).catch(error);
    sampleFunc4("sample4","promise-fail").then (log).catch(error);
    
    sampleFunc1("sample1","callback-fail",info);
    local.sampleFunc2("sample2","callback-fail",info);
    sampleFunc3("sample3","callback-fail",info);
    sampleFunc4("sample4","callback-fail",info);
```

```js
    var cpArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);

    function promiseToCB (nm,fn,THIS) {
        if (typeof nm==='function') {
            THIS=fn;fn=nm;nm=fn.name;
        }
        THIS=THIS||this;
        const func = function () {
           let args = cpArgs(arguments);
            if (typeof args[args.length-1]==='function') {
                const cb = args.pop();
                return fn.apply(THIS,args).then(function(r){
                   cb (undefined,r);
                }).catch(cb);  
            } else {
                return fn.apply(THIS,args);
            }
        };
        Object.defineProperty(func,'name',{value:nm,enumerable:false,configurable: true});
        if (THIS[nm]) delete THIS[nm];
        Object.defineProperty(THIS,nm,{value:func,enumerable:false,configurable: true});
        return func;
    }

    function cbToPromise (nm,fn,THIS) {
        if (typeof nm==='function') {
            THIS=fn;fn=nm;nm=fn.name;
        }
        THIS=THIS||this;
        const func = function () {
           let args = cpArgs(arguments);
            if (typeof args[args.length-1]==='function') {
                return fn.apply(THIS,args);
            } else {
                return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
                    
                    args.push(function(err,result){
                          if (err) return reject(err);
                          if (arguments.length==2) {
                             return resolve(result);
                          }
                          return resolve(cpArgs(arguments,1));
                    });
                              
                    fn.apply(THIS,args);
                    
                });
            }
        };
        Object.defineProperty(func,'name',{value:nm,enumerable:false,configurable: true});
        if (THIS[nm]) delete THIS[nm];
        Object.defineProperty(THIS,nm,{value:func,enumerable:false,configurable: true});
        return func;

    }

    function asPromise (args,resolver,no_err) {
        const cb = args[args.length-1],
        promise  = new Promise(resolver);
        return (typeof cb==='function')  ? promise.then(function(result){return cb(no_err,result)}).catch(cb) : promise;
    }

    function asCallback (args,wrap,no_err) {
        const cb = args[args.length-1],
        promise=new Promise(function resolver(resolve,reject) {
            return wrap (function (err,result) {
                 if (err) return reject(err);
                 resolve(result);
            });
        });
        return (typeof cb==='function')  ? promise.then(function(result){return cb(no_err,result)}).catch(cb) : promise;
    }


    function cbPromiseTest(){
        /*global sampleFunc1,sampleFunc2*/
        
        const local = {}; 
        promiseToCB(function sampleFunc1(arg1,arg2) {
            console.log("deciding:",arg1,arg2);
            return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
           
               const timer = setTimeout(function(){reject([arg1,arg2,"ouch"].join("-"));},5000);
               
               setTimeout(function(){
                   if (arg2.endsWith("-pass") || (!arg2.endsWith("-fail") && Math.random()<0.5)) {
        
                       console.log("complete:",arg1,arg2);
                       clearTimeout(timer);
                       resolve([arg1,arg2,"all good"].join("-"));
                   }
               },2000);
            
            });
        });
        
        cbToPromise('sampleFunc2',function someOtherName(arg1,arg2,cb) {
           console.log("deciding:",arg1,arg2);
           const timer = setTimeout(function(){cb([arg1,arg2,"ouch"].join("-"));},5000);
           
           setTimeout(function(){
               if (arg2.endsWith("-pass") || (!arg2.endsWith("-fail") && Math.random()<0.5)) {
                   console.log("complete:",arg1,arg2);
                   clearTimeout(timer);
                   cb(undefined,[arg1,arg2,"all good"].join("-"));
               }
           },2000);
            
        },local);
        
        function sampleFunc3(arg1,arg2) {return asPromise(arguments,function(resolve,reject){
           console.log("deciding:",arg1,arg2);
           const timer = setTimeout(function(){reject([arg1,arg2,"ouch"].join("-"));},5000);
           
           setTimeout(function(){
               if (arg2.endsWith("-pass") || (!arg2.endsWith("-fail") && Math.random()<0.5)) {
                   console.log("complete:",arg1,arg2);
                   clearTimeout(timer);
                   resolve([arg1,arg2,"all good"].join("-"));
               }
           },2000);
            
        });}
        
        function sampleFunc4(arg1,arg2) {return asCallback(arguments,function(cb){
           console.log("deciding:",arg1,arg2);
           const timer = setTimeout(function(){cb([arg1,arg2,"ouch"].join("-"));},5000);
           
           setTimeout(function(){
               if (arg2.endsWith("-pass") || (!arg2.endsWith("-fail") && Math.random()<0.5)) {
                   console.log("complete:",arg1,arg2);
                   clearTimeout(timer);
                   cb(undefined,[arg1,arg2,"all good"].join("-"));
               }
           },2000);
            
        });}
        
        const log=console.log.bind(console),info=console.info.bind(console),error=console.error.bind(console);
        
        sampleFunc1("sample1","promise").then (log).catch(error);
        local.sampleFunc2("sample2","promise").then (log).catch(error);
        sampleFunc3("sample3","promise").then (log).catch(error);
        sampleFunc4("sample4","promise").then (log).catch(error);

        sampleFunc1("sample1","callback",info);
        local.sampleFunc2("sample2","callback",info);
        sampleFunc3("sample3","callback",info);
        sampleFunc4("sample4","callback",info);
        
        sampleFunc1("sample1","promise-pass").then (log).catch(error);
        local.sampleFunc2("sample2","promise-pass").then (log).catch(error);
        sampleFunc3("sample3","promise-pass").then (log).catch(error);
        sampleFunc4("sample4","promise-pass").then (log).catch(error);

        sampleFunc1("sample1","callback-pass",info);
        local.sampleFunc2("sample2","callback-pass",info);
        sampleFunc3("sample3","callback-pass",info);
        sampleFunc4("sample4","callback-pass",info);
        
        
        sampleFunc1("sample1","promise-fail").then (log).catch(error);
        local.sampleFunc2("sample2","promise-fail").then (log).catch(error);
        sampleFunc3("sample3","promise-fail").then (log).catch(error);
        sampleFunc4("sample4","promise-fail").then (log).catch(error);
        
        sampleFunc1("sample1","callback-fail",info);
        local.sampleFunc2("sample2","callback-fail",info);
        sampleFunc3("sample3","callback-fail",info);
        sampleFunc4("sample4","callback-fail",info);
     
    }
    cbPromiseTest();
```

Answer (score 0):

since we know the characteristics of a callback-based function in advance,
we can create a function that transforms a callback-based function
into an equivalent function returning a Promise.

- The callback is the last argument of the function
- If there is an error, it always the first argument passed to the callback
- Any return value is passed after the error to the callback

  ```
   function promisify(yourCallbackApi) {
      return function promisified(...args) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          // newArgs=[..args,callback]
          const newArgs = [
            ...args,
            function (err, result) {
              if (err) {
                return reject(err);
              }
              resolve(result);
            },
          ];
          // invoke yourCallbackApi with the new list of arguments
          yourCallbackApi(...newArgs);
        });
      };
    }
  ```

Answer (score -3):

It is like 5 years late, but I wanted to post here my promesify version which takes functions from callbacks API and turns them into promises

```
const promesify = fn => {
  return (...params) => ({
    then: cbThen => ({
      catch: cbCatch => {
        fn(...params, cbThen, cbCatch);
      }
    })
  });
};
```

Take a look to this very simple version here:
https://gist.github.com/jdtorregrosas/aeee96dd07558a5d18db1ff02f31e21a

Comment: That's not a promise, it doesn't chain, deal with errors thrown in the callback or accept a second parameter in then...